# How to see Children().ToList() method in JEnumerable<JToken> object?

Tags: c#, json, linq, windows-phone-7, json.net

I try to parse JSON by JSON.NET and in App class is OK, but if I want write parse method in custom class, VS don't see method `ToList()` in `JEnumerable<JToken>` object.

Listing:

```
JObject newsResponse = JObject.Parse(e.Result);
IList<JToken> results = newsResponse["NewsResponse"]["NewsItems"]["NewsItem"].Children().ToList(); //Here don't see ToList()
List<News> newsResults = new List<News>();

foreach (JToken result in results)
{
    News searchResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<News>(result.ToString());
    newsResults.Add(searchResult);
}
```

**Error:**

> 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JEnumerable' does
>   not contain a definition for 'ToList' and no extension method 'ToList'
>   accepting a first argument of type
>   'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JEnumerable' could
>   be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Why do you need the `ToList()`? Maybe you could replace `IList<JToken>` by `var` and remove the `ToList()`.

Comment: I'll post it as an answer then :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need to use `ToList()` here.

```
var results = newsResponse["NewsResponse"]["NewsItems"]["NewsItem"].Children();
```

This will produce an Enumerable (lazy) collection usable with your `foreach` below.

Note: I'm using var since I don't know the exact type returned here, but we don't really care for it, and it's probably quite complicated, so that's really useful.

Answer (score 1):

Since I am not able to comment on jv42's Answer and since I do not like anonymous types, I will build on his answer a bit.

You should not need to use `.ToList()` as mentioned above, and the results will become a `JEnumerable` which can be `foreach`'ed through:

```
JEnumerable results = newsResponse["NewsResponse"]["NewsItems"]["NewsItem"].Children();

foreach( JToken result in results )
{
    Console.WriteLine(result.ToString());
}
```

Comment: `var` is quite different from an anonymous type, it's only a keyword telling the compiler to fill in the type for you, you're still using static typing and the type of the expression doesn't change (no conversion or anything).